# My Two Wheeler scooter - Powers OFF Intermittently while driving

Tags: scooter, cold-start, two-stroke, combustion-cycle, combustion-chamber

I am using a two wheeler (Petrol/Gasoline vehicle).

I haven't driven the vehicle for like 30-40 days.

Today I had a trouble turning ON the vehicle. 
After some tries, I managed to turn it ON Successfully.

But while starting to ride it. the engine goes OFF intermittently. 
I am not sure whether its the engine or something else which goes OFF. But what I actually mean is that, while riding, the vehicle powers DOWN intermittently. I try to raise the acceleration, but sometimes, the vehicle stays ON but sometimes it goes OFF.

I am guessing that as the vehicle was dormant for over a month, the fuel would have been cold and while starting, the temperature wasn't high enough for the combustion to occur properly.

But what is happening while I am riding the vehicle and it goes OFF?

Comment: cold fuel is not going to be the issue (unless you are somewhere that's down at eg -30C) however you could consider the fuel could be contaminated, filters could have crud in them etc

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more on what might be the reason

Comment: Rory Alsop did so, saying you should consider that the fuel might be contaminated. Contamination could either be water or tangible bits of dirt or grit. If there's a fuel filter, remove and clean it. Then remove the fuel tank and fuel lines, drain the tank, rinse so its completely clean, blow out the fuel lines so you know they're clean, then reassemble and fill with new fuel. Test, and report back.